# Flash CS3 (AS3) is giving my graphics (buttons and movieclips) outlines

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, graphics, adobe-flash-cs3

So, I'm pretty much a beginner in Flash and Actionscript (using AS3, as I said in the title), and I'm trying to make a basic escape the room game. I haven't gotten far, and right now that's because every time I test my game (or publish preview it) the graphics get this annoying outline. Here it is when tested: http://i305.photobucket.com/albums/nn228/chokingondrama/flash.png

Every outline corresponds to some object present in the game, most of which have an alpha component of 0 since they're on different sides of the room. This didn't happen before, but once I added the code that allowed the player to change their view with the arrow (each viewpoint/wall is a different frame) these appeared.

It's a little different when published to HTML, basically it just gives each image a white background: http://i305.photobucket.com/albums/nn228/chokingondrama/html.png

Also, it would be nice if somebody could give me advice on how to make sure importing to flash won't result in lower quality.

Thanks in advance. If needed, I'll post any part of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tips:

Don't set alpha to 0, instead use the visible property, setting movieclip.visible = false will make it a lot more efficient.

As for the importing and quality, after you import to stage or library, bring up the library (ctrl + l), and right click on the file you imported, go to properties. If it's an image, set compression to lossless, and allow smoothing.

For audio, go to file-> publish settings, and change audio stream and audio event (whichever you might use) to 128kbps.

As for your main question, I need more info, if you want you can post your source. It might be because of how you are placing your graphics on the stage.

Comment: Thanks, using .visible instead of .alpha actually fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

For each of your MovieClips in question:

Try disabling button mode and see if the rectangles go away.

```
movieClipName.buttonMode = false;
```

If that doesn't help, or you really want button mode, try setting

```
movieClipName.tabEnabled = false;
```

There's a chance that since you added keyboard interaction each of your MovieClips are now expecting to be selected by the user when they press the tab key, much like any normal web form.

[tabEnabled in the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#tabEnabled)

You could also try

```
movieClipName.focusRect = false;
```

[focusRect in the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#focusRect)